# Content Blocks Backend not loading

Tags: admin, error, json, magento2.2.2

I'm not sure what caused this but out of nowhere my blocks in the backend of my Magento is not loading it sits there with a loading icon. https://imgur.com/a/9Osu2

I am also getting this error with a testing app

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 85512
>    /mag2/admin_wn/cms/block/index/key/51437802668f4a31878d4716a028c355039b45eababcfdf8d8a951fa07ed2b47/:1

```
Magento Version: 2.2.2

PHP Verison: ea-php71

Litespeed Verison: 

5.2.3 (build 0) Active
MariaDB:  10.1

Cloudlinux: CLOUDLINUX 6.9
```

**I've tried the following:**

1. Increasing max_memory from 128M to 512M.
2. Full System Restart / MYSQL Restart/Litespeed Restart
3. Cleared Local Cache/DNS/Restarted Computer/Different PC/Internet
4. Cleared Static/Var folders/files.
5. Reindexed

Comment: Increase memory_limit from 512MB to 2G